# Create several records at once in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app users can create a set of codes to used in marketing activities. Therefore I want a form in which a user can type the amount of codes he want to create and then the system should generate that many codes and save them to the database.

**code.rb**

```
class Code < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :form

   attr_accessor :amount
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for [:customer, @code] do |f| %>

  <% if @code.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@code.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this code from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @code.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :amount %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :amount %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

What I want to do now is to tell the controller:

1. take :amount
2. create as many SecureRandom.hex(3) as :amount specifies
3. save all codes to database (column for the codes in the table is named "code")

**However, I totally don't know how to achieve this...**

Comment: This is not place where someone will write code instead of you. Show what you have so far, and what exactly your problem is.

Comment: What I have so far is in my post and my problem is that I don't know how to continue now...

Comment: @Oliver, Can you explain me what you want to implement?

Comment: I want a user to type in e. g. 200 in the :amount field and then the controller generates 200 times a SecureRandom.hex(3) and save each to the database.

Comment: `params[:amount].to_i.times { Code.create(:key => SecureRandom.hex(3)) } ` ? But that's slow. Check out activerecord-import gem for a good, easy, elegant solution to bulk-insert without having to make the round-trip.

Comment: Hi, you wrote down the pseudo code already... I would just create the controller method (create) and handle the usecase you described.

Comment: Thanks @JoshBrody! The gem helped a lot!